# Javascript global variable with async/await is set, but later undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm setting up a mongoDB endpoint with NodeJS. [Implementing this backend](https://github.com/beaucarnes/restaurant-reviews)
I seem to have a problem with the code where the function `static async injectDB` sets  a global variable `let restaurants` which another function `static async getRestaurants` accesses, but then it turned into `undefined`

```
import mongodb from "mongodb"
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectID

let restaurants

export default class RestaurantsDAO {|


static async injectDB(conn) {
   if (restaurants) {
      return
   }
   try {
       restaurants = await conn.db(process.env.RESTREVIEWS_NS).collection("restaurants") 
   } catch (e) {
     console.error(
      `Unable to establish a collection handle in restaurantsDAO: ${e}`,
     )
   }
}

static async getRestaurants({
   filters = null,
   page = 0,
   restaurantsPerPage = 20,
   } = {}) {


  console.log(restaurants)   // undefined

  ...
```

`getRestaurants` is of course called at a much later point than `injectDB`, if I `console.log(restaurants)` in that function, it writes out its values. But its undefined when the other function is called. Why is that?

The `injectDB` function is called at server start, while the `getRestaurants` is called when someone acceesses the endpoint.

An alternative solution is to open the connection to DB in the `getRestaurants` function, is that best practice?

See full code for [restaurantsDAO.js](https://github.com/beaucarnes/restaurant-reviews/blob/master/backend/dao/restaurantsDAO.js)

Comment: Depends; but you're relying on timing to access a variable that won't be initialized until an arbitrary time in the future--not generally an effective way to do async programming.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks. I'm not trying to build a very effective way of doing it, just stuck on my first ever attempt at a mongoDB backend, so would be more helpful if you have suggestions on how to share this variable between the functions

Comment: You don't; you approach it as normal JS async programming. I'd *strongly* suggest some tutorials/examples. The [canonical SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992) is likely to be somewhat confusing without some basics.

Comment: @DaveNewton also useful [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: Your title is wrong. **Later** it will get its value. However **now** (the place you console.log) it is undefined. Remember, **later** it will be defined. The `await` keyword allows you to wait for **later** (alternatively, the `.then()` method allows you to execute code **later** so you can use the value)

Comment: Seems weird no one else that followed the course had this problem though, maybe i'm missing something

Comment: @slebetman but the console log is called much later though, since that is called when an endpoint returns from a GET, while the injectDB is called at server start

Comment: In that case it should work. You should add that information to your question.

Comment: One issue I think why nobody is getting your question is we don't see how and were you're calling those functions. And yes, probably most experienced javascript developers would not know what course you're talking about.

Comment: @slebetman i've updated the question with the details. I wonder if its best practice to do the conn.db in the getRestaurants endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that you cannot know if the `await` code has finished unless you check for it. It can really help to put console.logs everywhere! See this example:

```
export default class RestaurantsDAO {

    static restaurants

    static async injectDB(conn) {
        if (RestaurantsDAO.restaurants) {
            return
        }
        try {
            console.log("start loading")
            RestaurantsDAO.restaurants = await conn.db(process.env.RESTREVIEWS_NS).collection("restaurants")
            console.log("finished loading restaurants!")
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(
                `Unable to establish a collection handle in restaurantsDAO: ${e}`,
            )
        }
    }

    static showRestaurants() {
        if (RestaurantsDAO.restaurants) {
            console.log("restaurants are loaded")
        } else {
            console.log("restaurants not yet loaded")
        }
    }
}
```

So if you call `injectDB`  anywhere else in your code, that doesn't guarantee that `restaurants` is filled right away.

```
import RestaurantsDAO from "./restaurantsdao.js"

RestaurantsDAO.injectDB(..)           // console: "start loading"
RestaurantsDAO.showRestaurants()      // console: "restaurants not yet loaded"
// console: "finished loading" (because await has finished)
```

BTW I think it makes more sense if you make the `restaurants` variable part of the class, instead of defining it outside of the class on the module.

Comment: Yeah this works and confirms it's not really await/async i have a problem with. It's the RestaurantsDAO.restaurants is nulled out between injectDB and the other callback. Maybe i have to add a new SO question for that case though

Comment: You could make the `injectDB` function also return a promise by using `return await conn.db()`, and then your external code can use `restaurants = await RestaurantsDAO.injectDB()`. That way, you don't even have to store the results in the static variable at all.

Comment: So you recommend to not use global variables together with `async/await`? I have two async functions and need the same url in both functions. Should I declare the url in both?